# How to check for 2-way relationship in data frame?

Tags: r

If I have a data frame in a format like this

```
mydata <- data.frame(donor = c("Person A", "Person A", "Person A", "Person B", 
      "Person B", "Person C"), recipient = c("Person B", "Person C", "Person F", 
       "Person A", "Person C", "Person B"), Total = c(30, 40, 12, 75, 80, 20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And I want to find out the net donations between each pair, what is an efficient way (or any way) to find out whether there's a listing for both Person A as donor and Person B as recipient AND Person B as donor and Person A as recipient so to then find the net between them?

In other words, if Person A donated 40 to Person C but Person C didn't give anything to A, then the net donation from A to C is 40 (and from C to A is -40); but if A donated 30 to B and B donated 75 to A, then the net donation from A to B is -45 and B to A is +45.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a merge:

```
> res <- merge(mydata, mydata, by.x = c("donor", "recipient"), by.y = c("recipient", "donor"), suffixes = c(".donor", ".recipient"), all.x = TRUE)
> res$Net <- with(res, ifelse(is.na(Total.recipient), Total.donor, Total.donor - Total.recipient))
> res
     donor recipient Total.donor Total.recipient Net
1 Person A  Person B          30              75 -45
2 Person A  Person C          40              NA  40
3 Person A  Person F          12              NA  12
4 Person B  Person A          75              30  45
5 Person B  Person C          80              20  60
6 Person C  Person B          20              80 -60
```

Answer (score 0):

This calculates the net donations between pairs, where + means the donor gave more, and - means the recipient gave more

```
mydata$pair <- with(mydata, paste(pmin(donor, recipient), pmax(donor, 
     recipient), sep=","))
mydata$Total2 <- with(mydata, ifelse(donor < recipient, Total, -Total))
with(mydata, aggregate(Total2, list(pair), sum))

            Group.1   x
1 Person A,Person B -45
2 Person A,Person C  40
3 Person A,Person F  12
4 Person B,Person C  60
```